# An kdump tool issue with the customized kernel

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel

when we are using the kdump tool, we need to install the according kernel-debug*.rpm at first.

My questions is , the linux I am using is compiled by myself with lots of modifications. When could I find the kernel-debug*.rpm related to my customized kernel version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain if you are using Fedora, RHEL or CentOS to create your kernel.  For Fedora, a custom kernel-debug*.rpm is built from your source with the instructions given here:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_non-debugging_kernel#Building_a_non-debugging_kernel

using the **make release** target.